# How to write an initWith... on a viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I learned a very painful lesson about how to ensure your outlets are nil on a view controller's viewDidLoad, and that's by writing an initWith... method of your own.

```
-(id)initWithDoohickey:(SomeDoohickey*)doohickey
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self)
        {
            theDoohickey = doohickey;
        }
        return nil;
    }
```

Now when you call this method, instead of initWithNibName, or simply init, your view outlets will be nil, and you'll run into all kinds of debugging nightmares.

So I see two solutions here...
(1) Call init or initWithNibName and let it do it's thing, and follow that with a `classInQuestion configureWithDoohickey:(SomeDoohickey*)doohickey`

or (2)
figure out how to properly write an initWith... method that actually loads the nib properly, while also allowing me to pass in whatever config variables I want in the same call.

I'd like to know how to do (2).

Comment: Call `[super initWithNibName...]` instead of `[super init]`.

Comment: Can you post that as an answer so I can give you the credit as an answer?

Comment: Good reason to switch to Swift. It wouldn't have let you make this mistake.

Comment: @matt  lol, interesting.  I didn't know that.... among lots of other things, heh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace your call to `[super init];` with a call to `[super initWithNibName:...];`.

Obviously you need to pass in the correct arguments.

Comment: @matt The OP needs to call `initWithNibName...` because they are using a nib-based view controller. It has nothing to do with designated initializers. I don't use IB so I never use `initWithNibName` and all my view controllers work just fine.

Comment: @rmaddy, The rule is that in a custom init method you should call the designated initializer. (initWithNibName: in this case). If you don't use IB then the fact that you don't call the designated initializer doesn't do any harm, but it's still the right thing to do. If you publish a view controller for others to consume, say, and THEY use it from a nib, the fact that you don't call the designated initializer would likely cause problems.

Comment: In most cases, the correct arguments for `initWithNibName:bundle:` are `nil` and `nil`.

Comment: ...although view controllers are schizophrenic, and they can be created with either initWithNibName or initWithCoder, and you have to handle both cases. That's always bugged me.

Comment: @DuncanC Usually you don't have to handle either and just use `viewDidLoad`, actually.

Comment: "It has nothing to do with designated initializers" Oh yes it does.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you didn't properly [chain the initializers](https://blog.twitter.com/2014/how-to-objective-c-initializer-patterns). A subclass's initialization process must (eventually) call its superclass's [designated initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MultipleInitializers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH33-SW2). The designated initializer ensures that *all* of a class's data is correctly set up.

If you don't call the superclass's DI, it's not able to set the properties that were defined in the superclass.

The simple `init` that you're using is not `UIViewController`'s designated intializer; `initWithNibName:bundle:` is. As rmaddy said, *that* is the method you should use in your subclass's own designated intializer.

Initializers in the subclass can use each other, as long as one of them eventually passes up to the superclass's DI.

(As an aside, this relationship has been formalized in Swift. Initializer chaining is actually part of the language, rather than just a convention. This [can be confusing](http://www.edwardhuynh.com/blog/2015/02/16/swift-initializer-confusion/), but interestingly, the way you wrote `initWithDoohickey:` would not have even compiled in Swift.)